# Classifying motor imagery using EEG data

Tags: biomedical-engineering

I am an undergraduate student who is trying to classify motor imagery from EEG data!

I have no experience working with EEG or any neuroscience background, I only have a very basic knowledge of how EEG, ERD/ERS and frequency domain work from the papers I've tried to read but don't understand and the basic idea of what they are doing. I also have a reasonably basic knowledge of supervised Machine Learning.

I plan to use ERD/ERS to classify Left foot, Right hand and rest to classify motor imagery in real time!

**What is the easiest way to do this?**

So far I have bandpassed the data between 7-30 Hz for Mu and Beta wavelengths as they are the ones related to the motor imagery as well as removing the baseline and just plotted the Power Spectral Density. I passed this data through a basic SVM; linear and gaussian, optimised parameters with poor results (60% accuracy on average)

[image: Power Spectral Density]

I have no idea how to do feature extraction, where to start, how to properly classify EEG data. and how to do this in real time.

**If someone could guide me and provide the steps on how to proceed I would extremely grateful!**

I want to work in the field of Brain Computer Interfaces as I find it fascinating, this is my first step :)

Here is the link to the dataset and its details [BCI competition: IVc](http://www.bbci.de/competition/iii/desc_IVc.html)

Comment: Better posted on the Cross Validated Stack? But check first.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look